# Accessing Inbox and SentItems folder on EWS using powershell

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I'm struggling with some EWS via PowerShell code. It seems I can't access both the Sent Items and the Inbox folders at the same time.

Here's my code:

```
$ewsPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
Add-Type -Path $ewsPath
$ews = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService -ArgumentList "Exchange2013"
$ews.Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential('emailbox', 'password')
$ews.AutodiscoverUrl("emailbox@domain.com")
$inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($ews,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)
$sentbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($ews,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::SentItems)
$iv = New-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView -ArgumentList 10000                                         
$pvSet = New-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)                                               
$sentItems = $sentbox.FindItems($iv)
```

When I want to get the Sent Items folder in the `sentbox` variable I get the following error:

> Exception when calling "Bind" with "2" argument (s): "The request
>   failed. The remote server returned an error: (501) Not implemented.

But if I had the following line between the $inbox and $sentbox initialization it works, but the findItems on $sentbox fails.

```
$ews.AutodiscoverUrl("emailbox@domain.com")
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code your using eg the error you getting is for FindItems and the code you have posted in doing a Bind (GetItem) this is not related so you must have other code your running where the error is occurring

Comment: Sorry had some bad copypasta because i was still debugging.
So the thing is that the bind on my $sentbox fails. But if i redo the discoverurl() before my second bind, the $sentitems bind works but the findItems still fails.

Comment: That really makes no sense all Autodiscover does is populate the server.url value that shouldn't change once discovered. You might want to enable tracing and look at the request going to the server eg $service.TraceEnabled = $true . I'd also give the ewseditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ a go just clicking the Inbox and then Sent Items would do exactly the same thing as your code is trying to do with the same underlying dll etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue about firewalls.
The code works.